# Can a Linux process block external signals but accept signals from its own process?

Tags: linux, process, signals

I am trying to setup a Linux process, which blocks `SIGTERM` that is sent from `kill` command (or any other process), but allows `SIGTERM` to be sent from within itself (through `kill(2)` system call).

Is it possible?

Here is an example program that I wrote, but it `SIG_BLOCKS` both external and internal signals, so it doesn't do what I want:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  sigset_t sigs;

  sigemptyset(&sigs);
  sigaddset(&sigs, SIGTERM);
  sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigs, 0);

  printf("Sleeping 30 secs, try killing me! (pid: %d)\n", getpid());
  sleep(30);
  printf("About to call kill\n");
  kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
  printf("This never happens!\n");

  return 1;
}
```

The output is:

```
Sleeping 30 secs, try killing me! (pid: 29416)
About to call kill
This never happens!
```

But it should be:

```
Sleeping 30 secs, try killing me! (pid: 29416)
About to call kill
```

Because the process should get killed from within through `kill(getpid(), SIGTERM)`.

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to accomplish?  (Not *how*, but *what*.)

Comment: @pilcrow : this is a theoretical question I want to settle with my friend. He said if an external process can't kill a process, then a process can't kill itself either. I want to show him that you can setup signal handler in a way that external signals will get ignored but internal (from within app itself) will get accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but you can set up a signal handler using `sigaction` with the `SA_SIGINFO` flag, have your `SIGTERM` handler only call `_exit` if `siginfo.si_pid` is your PID

Comment: +1 This is the closest way to simulate the semantics the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I test if you don't block the signal. you can see the expected behaviour.

But if you blocked the signal, the kill will return with value 0, and since the program continue to execute,it'll print the line and exit. I'm using ubuntu 12.04LTS for testing.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is according to your comment:

> this is a theoretical question I want to settle with my friend. He said if an external process can't kill a process, then a process can't kill itself either.

**It's possible to block signals and still to kill yourself.** Using `abort()` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html):

> The abort() function first unblocks the SIGABRT signal, and then
> raises that signal for the calling process (as though raise(3)
> was called).  This results in the abnormal termination of the
> process unless the SIGABRT signal is caught and the signal
> handler does not return (see longjmp(3)).
>
> If the SIGABRT signal is ignored, or caught by a handler that
> returns, the abort() function will still terminate the process.
> It does this by restoring the default disposition for SIGABRT and
> then raising the signal for a second time.